# transfer all records from one database table to another database table

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have records in one database table and I want to transfer all into a table in a different database.

my current code can only transfer between tables in the same database.

````
 Statement st = conn.createStatement();
 int rows = st.executeUpdate("Insert into script(ID,Name) Select ID,Name from table1");
 if(rows==0){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Nothing to transfer.");
 }else{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rows+" transfered successfully into script");
 }
}catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}finally{
 try{
 rs.close();
 pst.close();
     }
 catch(Exception e){
     }
     } 

//and below are my database connections. 


public into_databses(){

conn = connector.db1();
conn1 = connector.db2();
}

//and I am currently using only   conn=connector.db1```

I want to modify it so that I can transfer records between tables in the different databases. thank you
````

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: sqlite3 @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sqlite3, you want [ATTACH DATABASE](https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

With the destination database connection, run these statements:

```sql
ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS source;
INSERT INTO main.script(ID, Name) SELECT ID, Name FROM source.table1;
DETACH source; -- optional
```

where `other.db` is the file name of the database you want to copy from.

Dealing with constraint violations from things like duplicate primary keys is left as an exercise for the reader - `INSERT` has various ways to handle such things that might or might not work for you, depending on your needs.